# How to modify an unique row from duplicated rows

Tags: pervasive-sql

I am working with an existing Pervasive **v10** database. In a table I have duplicated rows without an unique descriptor (no primary key).

I would like to modify only the first row with the SQL command update. The table History have 3 columns only :

- Document : a VARCHAR
- Link : a number
- Description : a VARCHAR

The result of :

```
select * from History where Document = 'IN10001' and Link = 3
```

is giving 2 identical rows :

> 'IN10001'; 3; 'Invoice 2'
>
> 'IN10001'; 3; 'Invoice 2'

Could someone help me to change the field: Link for only one row?

Comment: How will you know which record to update if it isn't unique?  This seems like a flaw in the table design.  You can use the TOP clause to limit the number of records in a SELECT statement but I'm not sure if you can do that in an UPDATE>

Comment: I need to update Link in only one row. Effectively the database design isn't good and i can't change it.

Comment: Without being able to uniquely identify the record to update, you're not going to be able to use a standard SQL statement.  If you know you have duplicate values, go into the app that generated the data and fix them there.